# How can I filter images together in 3 dimensions

Tags: python, image, filter, convolution, smoothing

I have a sequence of images and I want to filter them in 3 dimension. The spatial filter is gaussian filter and for temporal filtering I use sinc filter so as spatial an temporal kernels are separable, first I implement gaussian filter for each image and then I save all images in a 3D array and convolve the array with a sinc filter in only t axis. But when I'm looking at the result all of my images become exactly simillar to each other like all of them are one image. Here is my code please tell me where I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
t = np.linspace(0,32,32)
h2= np.array(np.sinc(t-2.5))[:,None,None]
for filename in glob.glob('02291G0AR/*.bmp'):
    img = np.array(Image.open(filename).convert('I;16'))
    src = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 5,cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    img_array.append(src)

v = np.array(img_array)
k1 = signal.fftconvolve(v,h2,mode='same')
plt.figure(3)
plt.imshow(k1[0,:,:],cmap='gray')
plt.figure(4)
plt.imshow(k1[2,:,:],cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Don't think it's required, but could you add examples images of the result? Would help visualize the issue and perhaps more people would be inclined to help (as it lowers the threshold for people to understand). Guessing it's not possible for you to create a "desired outcome" image either? Or perhaps you have an example?